# Redo Windows 10 setup after installing drivers

Tags: windows-10, drivers, setup

I have a computer I'm building to sell.  It needs drivers (mainly for the graphics card), but I don't want to sell a computer that is already set up.  Is there a way to rerun the setup after I have installed the drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the drivers installed (makes sense), you can use the OEM System Builder install and charge the user for the OEM license.

That does what you need and gives the user the license (at their cost) that goes with the drivers.

This will work.

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll give it a shot.  Just to make sure, is this what you're talking about? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/system-builder-deployment-of-windows-10-for-desktop-editions

Comment: Yes, that is what I am referring to.